# How to use Spring Initializr (1)?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

How to use Spring Initializr https://start.spring.io/ in order to create a project and then create a maven JAR from this project in order to put it into a Docker container as described in [This tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) ?

After unzipping and importing the zip file generated by Spring Initializr into Eclipse via *File > Import* there is a demo application under `/src/main/java` and a test application under `/src/test/java`. That are already two projects with their own `main(String[] args)` functions. **Where am I supposed to add my own project?**

I am supposed to add the class file Application.java under *src > main > java > hello* with the following code

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "Hello Docker World";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

What is it as what I have to create the code posted above? As class? As project?

When I click on *src > main > java* and then *right-click*, then in the opening context menu *New > Folder* a new project pops up under the maven folder `src/main/java` and it has some symbol before it which is a white cube cut in half horizontally and vertically. I believe the "project"-symbol is not white but reddish?

(A `hello-Folder` under *src > main > java > hello* is NOT created.)

But now: *What* is it that I have to create when right-clicking the `<symbol> hello` entry ?

So I *right-click* on that project-symbol in the Eclipse Project-Explorer *New > Class*

In the dialogue that pops up, `Source folder` is set to `demo/src/main/java`, `Package` is set to `hello`, I give it the `Name` of `Application` and then -> `Finish`

The color of the cube-symbol before the hello package changes from white to reddish.

It has the file Application.java under it, in which I copy the code posted above.

The workbench directory is still completely empty (!!!)

I select the project and click on `Run` in the menu and chose `run as java project`

I get an error message `Errors exist in required projects

Obviously it can't resolve the dependencies. What the heck?

Those lines cause the errors

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
```

How is that possible. I have imported the `pom.xml` ? What is missing?

I right-click `pom.xml` > Maven > Update Project

No avail. It can obviously still not load the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

After going through your question, what I understand is that you want to add a controller class in the project that you just unzipped. Right?

For that do the following.

1. Unzip the project again.
2. Open in Eclipse
3. Run maven build command to resolve the dependencies. (It's ok if it failed for
   now).
4. Right click on demo/src/main/java and go to new->Other. select class and then next. write the name of the controller class and then finish.